# Remove duplicates in a variable number of columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which removes duplicates from exactly 3 columns.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
'
' RemoveDuplicates Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'

    Intersect(Selection.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=Array(1,2,3), _
        Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

The problem is in the `Array(1, 2, 3)` - I want the number of columns to match `Selection.Columns.Count`, i.e. if there is 1 column it is `Array(1)` or if there are 4 columns it is `Array(1, 2, 3, 4)`, so I need to be able to build this dynamically.

I've tried building an Array of `Long`s, copying this into a `Variant`, and doing a `Split(Join(...))`, but passing any of these into the method gives me an error:

```
Run-time error  '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

Using the `Array()` function seems to be the only valid argument, but I can't build this dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The column array needs to be passed `byval` and not `byref`.

use **(** arrCols **)** not arrCols

---

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng         As Range
    Dim lCtr        As Long

    Dim arrCols()
    Dim arrTemp

    Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A1:C11")
    arrTemp = Split("1,2", ",")

    ReDim arrCols(0 To UBound(arrTemp))

    For lCtr = LBound(arrTemp) To UBound(arrTemp)
        arrCols(lCtr) = arrTemp(lCtr)
    Next

    '/ VBA needs the array to be passed by value. Use (arrCols), notice the parenthesis!
    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(arrCols), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: What would the difference between `Columns:=(arrCols)` and `Columns:=arrCols` be?

Comment: `Columns:=(arrCols)` is ByVal and `Columns:=arrCols` is ByRef (Same is highlighted in the answer :) ). Read this : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx

Comment: I think it would be worth detailing this a little more in the answer itself.

Comment: A very interesting result!  Can you shed any light on _why_ `Columns` needs to be passed `ByVal`?

Comment: @chrisneilsen there is no documentation around it from MS. At least nothing that I could find out. I settled by classifying it as one of many Excel tantrums.

Comment: Thank you for this. The only other thing I would add to your answer is that the array you pass in has to be a 0-based array (and the column numbers are 1-based). I used `ReDim arrCols(0 To rng.Columns.Count - 1)`, and `For lCtr = 0 To rng.Columns.Count - 1: arrCols(lCtr) = lCtr + 1: Next` and didn't need the temporary array `arrTemp`.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the `Array(1, 2, 3)` from the code. It worked for me

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).RemoveDuplicates , Header:=xlYes
```