VBA Array not working as expected. Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3) works, but Columns:=test fails, even if test = Array(1,2,3)
I was trying to write a macro where I could remove duplicates from a table without having to manually write out all the columns in the table using "Array(1,2,....)"
However, for some reason it seems impossible. See below my code where I attempt 2 different methods of removing duplicates.
Method 1 works by manually typing out the array. However, method 2 fails if I try to store it in a variable. Any proposed solutions or ideas why this is happening?
Sub RemoveDups()
    Dim test As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' Define the array for testing
    test = Array(1, 2, 3)
    
    ' Use the test array for RemoveDuplicates

    'Method 1
    [Table].RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes 'This works
    
    'Method 2
    [Table].RemoveDuplicates Columns:=test, Header:=xlYes 'This does not work
End Sub


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558576/remove-duplicates-in-a-variable-number-of-columns
Dim rng         As Range

Dim lCtr        As Long

Dim arrCols()

Dim arrTemp

Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A1:C11")

arrTemp = Split("1,2", ",")

ReDim arrCols(0 To UBound(arrTemp))

For lCtr = LBound(arrTemp) To UBound(arrTemp)

    arrCols(lCtr) = arrTemp(lCtr)

Next

'/ VBA needs the array to be passed by value. Use (arrCols), notice the parenthesis!

rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(arrCols), Header:=xlYes


@Michal At least in Excel 365, Columns:=Array(1,2,3) and r=Array(1,2,3): Columns:=(r) works the same if Option Base 0 which is by default. They both don't work with Option Base 1, So, no extra code required.
